# Calling script using path with whitespaces

Tags: python, tkinter, path

I have a GUI and I am using a button to call a python script.

I am using `python os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))` to get the directory of the GUI script and using it further to call the script which is in a sub-folder in that same directory.

I get the path of the GUI using:

```py
sPfad = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

```py
print(sPfad)

T:\kst597\common\FB\Reporting\Web\Datenladung in SAP
```

and I store the path of the script I want to call here:

```py
feld_script_man = sPfad+"\Felddaten\Konverter_Claims_MAN\Konverter_Felddaten_MAN.py"
```

I call the script using:

```py
os.system("python "+feld_script_man+" 1")
```

The error I get:

```py
python: can't open file 'T:\kst597\common\FB\Reporting\Web\Datenladung': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I also make sure the path exists:

```py
print(os.path.exists(sPfad+"\Felddaten\Konverter_Claims_MAN\Konverter_Felddaten_MAN.py"))

True
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: beware of backslashes use raw prefix: `r"\Felddaten\Konverter_Claims_MAN\Konverter_Felddaten_MAN.py"`

Comment: second, quote the arg because there are spaces in it (`T:\kst597\common\FB\Reporting\Web\Datenladung in SAP`), or better, use `subprocess.run` with a _list_ of arguments, don't compose the command yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, `os.path.exists` returns `True`, but in `os.system` it's different as command line/argument parsing occurs:

```
os.system("python "+feld_script_man+" 1")
```

is expanded literally as

```
os.system("python T:\kst597\common\FB\Reporting\Web\Datenladung in SAP\Felddaten\Konverter_Claims_MAN\Konverter_Felddaten_MAN.py 1")
```

as you can see, there's no quoting, so python tries to open the first argument which is `T:\kst597\common\FB\Reporting\Web\Datenladung` and it fails.

Always use `subprocess` module (`os.system` is deprecated) and always use a list of arguments.

That should work:

```
subprocess.check_call(["python",sPfad+r"\Felddaten\Konverter_Claims_MAN\Konverter_Felddaten_MAN.py","1"])
```

Comment: I was unaware of ```os.system``` being deprecated so thank you for the very useful info!